# Why moodle saying Unable to save the cache config to file

Tags: php, linux, moodle, folder-permissions

I tried to give write permission to moodledata folder like

```
sudo chmod 777
```

Then i try  to run my moodle site but it's giving me

```
Unable to save the cache config to file.
```

I tried to clear cache using

```
php admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

But this command is also giving me same error

Comment: Double check if your `dataroot` config is correctly set (navigate to `moddledata` in bash and run `pwd` just to make sure). Then use that absolute path in `dataroot` to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

The most probable reason for this error is your storage space. clean your harddisk to enable new content storage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).